# Plotting variables by classes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would need to plot as bar chart the following columns

```
    %_Var1 %_Var2   %_Val1  %_Val2     Class
2   0.00    0.00    0.10    0.01        1
3   0.01    0.01    0.07    0.05        0
17  0.00    0.00    0.02    0.01        0
24  0.00    0.00    0.11    0.04        0
27  0.00    0.00    0.02    0.03        1
44  0.00    0.00    0.05    0.02        0
53  0.00    0.00    0.03    0.01        1
67  0.00    0.00    0.06    0.02        0
87  0.00    0.00    0.22    0.01        1
115 0.00    0.00    0.03    0.02        0
```

comparing the values having Class 1 and Class 0 respectively (i.e. bars which show each column of the dataframe, putting one beside the other the column for only Class 1 ad the column for Class 0.
So I should have 8 bars: 4 where 4 bars are for Class 1 and the remaining 4 for Class 0.
One column of Class 1 should be beside the same column for Class 0.
I tried as follows:

```
ax = df[["%_Var1", "%_Var2", "%_Var3" , "%_Var4"]].plot(kind='bar')
```

but the output is completely wrong, also writing     `ax = df[["%_Var1", "%_Var2", "%_Var3" , "%_Var4"]].Label.plot(kind='bar')`

I think I should consider a groupby in my code, in order to group by Classes, but I do not know how to set the order (plots are not my top skill)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try the seaborn way, melt the dataframe to long format and then hue on the class.

```
data = df.melt(id_vars=['class'], value_vars=['var1','var2','val1','val2'])

import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x='variable', y='value', hue='class', data=data, ci=0)
```

gives:

[image]

Or if you want to get the plot based on the class, simply change the hue and x axis..

```
sns.barplot(x='class', y='value', hue='variable', data = data, ci=0)
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Prateek. Just one question: what is variable in the first code?

Comment: after you melt the dataframe, it creates the columns called **variable** and **value**. **variable** column contains var1, var2, val1, val2 and **value** column contains the values. Try to see what data looks like after the first line. You'll get it. Also, you may refer to the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('Class').mean().plot.bar()
```

With `pivot_table` method you can summarise the data per group as well.

```
df.pivot_table(index='Class').plot.bar()
# df.pivot_table(columns='Class').plot.bar() # invert order
```

By default, it calculates the mean of your target-columns, but you can specify another aggregation method with `aggfunc='myfunc'` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cainã Max Couto-Silva